# Why is my app not installed? File not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml. I am trying to deploy app and mysql,I added network.

```
version: '3'
services:
  
  #PHP Service
  app:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/bookstack
    container_name: bookstack
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysql
      - DB_USER=quantox
      - DB_PASS=****
      - DB_DATABASE=bookstackapp
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - 6875:80
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 33060:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - TZ=Europe/Budapest
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstackapp
      - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf  
    networks:
      - app-network      

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

After I go for up -d
I got

```
  Name                Command             State                       Ports                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bookstack   /init                         Up      443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6875->80/tcp,:::6875->80/tcp
mysql       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:33060->3306/tcp,:::33060->3306/tcp
```

But in browser localhost:6875 shows

```
File not found.
```

Why? Both my app and mysql are on same network. What should I check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using volumes (-v flags) permissions issues can arise between the host OS and the container, you could avoid this issue by allowing you to specify the user PUID and group PGID.